# Ubuntu23.10 - fwupd Secure Boot dbx 371 Bricked my PC

Tags: 23.10, fwupd

I have 8 similar desktop PC's (FUJITSU FMVD3000RP) that are now used as Ubuntu 22.04 servers for internal training purposes.

We decided to try the latest version of Ubuntu, so updated one of them to Ubuntu23.10 via `do-release-upgrade`.
Upgrade went great. Now after the update `fwupdmgr` started notifying me about a firmware upgrade upon login.

```
❯ fwupdmgr get-updates
Devices with no available firmware updates:
 • CT2000P2SSD8
 • System Firmware
FUJITSU FMVD3000RP
│
└─UEFI dbx:
  │   Device ID:          362301da643102b9f38477387e2193e57abaa590
  │   Summary:            UEFI revocation database
  │   Current version:    220
  │   Minimum Version:    220
  │   Vendor:             UEFI:Linux Foundation
  │   Install Duration:   1 second
  │   GUIDs:              8b0c62fa-23e7-518d-b3b5-140d8afa6079 ← UEFI\CRT_C315E37690D6847D6603DB8C6F7B4C20AAE7C89AF3BF5E8E41C48416EA1DA5B4
  │                       d1264ba7-d302-581c-a295-9eb50889d4ba ← UEFI\CRT_C315E37690D6847D6603DB8C6F7B4C20AAE7C89AF3BF5E8E41C48416EA1DA5B4&ARCH_X64
  │                       4696463d-7b1c-5677-82bc-60365e2300b6 ← UEFI\CRT_3ADD1AE6861BFAEFFE8AAA37C4F5A96EBD1140E20A6C444D8862F83CB1FD52E5
  │                       02f1b3c1-65ae-50f5-8c3c-3f3bef6d3a51 ← UEFI\CRT_3ADD1AE6861BFAEFFE8AAA37C4F5A96EBD1140E20A6C444D8862F83CB1FD52E5&ARCH_X64
  │                       79b5a78e-39ff-527a-bcd8-22cc2492a7b7 ← UEFI\CRT_F03AD42F22177A4CAD97EF3ACA1A66D62DE02C5F73E7DF42AA61BD8086563049
  │                       906322dd-ef74-53ef-b4ea-3d35b662cf49 ← UEFI\CRT_F03AD42F22177A4CAD97EF3ACA1A66D62DE02C5F73E7DF42AA61BD8086563049&ARCH_X64
  │                       c6682ade-b5ec-57c4-b687-676351208742 ← UEFI\CRT_A1117F516A32CEFCBA3F2D1ACE10A87972FD6BBE8FE0D0B996E09E65D802A503
  │                       f8ba2887-9411-5c36-9cee-88995bb39731 ← UEFI\CRT_A1117F516A32CEFCBA3F2D1ACE10A87972FD6BBE8FE0D0B996E09E65D802A503&ARCH_X64
  │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
  │                       • Updatable
  │                       • Supported on remote server
  │                       • Needs a reboot after installation
  │                       • Device is usable for the duration of the update
  │                       • Only version upgrades are allowed
  │                       • Signed Payload
  │
  └─Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update:
        New version:      371
        Remote ID:        lvfs
        Release ID:       35287
        Summary:          UEFI Secure Boot Forbidden Signature Database
        Variant:          x64
        License:          Proprietary
        Size:             21.2 kB
        Created:          2023-05-09
        Urgency:          High
        Tested by DMC Group:
          Tested:         2023-07-11
          Distribution:   fedora 38 (workstation)
          Old version:    211
          Version[fwupd]: 1.9.2
        Tested by Jabra:
          Tested:         2023-07-03
          Distribution:   ubuntu 22.04
          Old version:    220
          Version[fwupd]: 1.9.3
        Vendor:           Linux Foundation
        Duration:         1 second
        Release Flags:    • Trusted metadata
                          • Is upgrade
        Description:
        Insecure versions of the Microsoft Windows boot manager affected by Black Lotus were added to the list of forbidden signatures due to a discovered security problem.This updates the dbx to the latest release from Microsoft.

        Before installing the update, fwupd will check for any affected executables in the ESP and will refuse to update if it finds any boot binaries signed with any of the forbidden signatures.Applying this update may also cause some Windows install media to not start correctly.
        Issue:            CVE-2022-21894
        Checksum:         fc3feb015df2710fcfa07583d31b5975ee398357016699cfff067f422ab91e13
```

similar updates were applied before, so I upgraded the firmware without giving much thought.

After the update, the machine fails to boot. POST checks run fine, then halts completely.
Pressing the keys (ESC, DEL, F1...) to enter BIOS/UEFI setting does not work (it says ENTERING SETTINGS but does not proceeds).
I did a CMOS CLEAR by removing the internal battery. It worked as confirmed by beep note on reboot and change of bootup screen, but it still fails to boot.

I removed all disks and memory from the dead machine, then placed them in the same model PC (FUJITSU FMVD3000RP) which was running Ubuntu22.04lts - then everything boot up fine.
Only notable difference between 22.04/23.10 being that 23.10 notifies me of the same firmware update.

The dead PC fails to boot into BIOS/UEFI screen, or from any disks that works on another machine, Ubuntu or Windows - it seems there is no way to make it boot.

I now have a few questions hope somebody can answer:

1. Is there a way to revive the dead PC? It simply stops after POST, can not enter BIOS settings and it does not boot from USB drives.
2. Is there a way to stop `fwupdmgr` notifying me about the motherboard UEFI updates (this one and possible future ones)?
3. What is the best way to report this to Ubuntu devs, about this potentially dangerous update?
4. Can you think of any fun ways to put the dead PC for a good use, besides a door stopper?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS will *release-upgrade* to 23.04 and not 23.10, so how did you upgrade your system?  or did you re-install? as your details as I read them have you using an *unsupported* upgrade path (that isn't scheduled to open until Jan 2024; its open only for QA testing currently in order to find problems!)  Your details seem incorrect to me (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release shows what is seen; from 22.04 the next release with "Supported: 1" is 23.04 and **not** 23.10)

Comment: i did it twice! ->23.04 ->23.10

Answer (score 1):

Super uncool, I'm sorry this has happened. This dbx update has been applied by over 10 million people, and this is the first case I've heard of it bricking a machine. It sounds like either super bad luck, or more likely bad system firmware that has run out if nvram space.

Can you open an upstream bug on fwupd GitHub please, and include the output of 'sudo fwupdtool hwids' and 'sudo fwupdtool get-devices' from a working machine of exactly the same type please (any Ubuntu version).

We can block the update on this specific hardware. As for recovery; I think your best bet is to try a firmware update or recovery using the OEM tools -- which might hopefully reset the nvram back to factory settings.

Comment: Wow thank you for the reply! So cool to receive an answer from the dev himself!
I have the installation moved to a working PC, if I could check the logs I can feedback the exact bios/firmware version and model ID of the bricked PC. If you could guide me it will be appreciated!

Comment: Even though all 8 of them looks mostly the same, the model designation printed on the machine is slightly different, (I know the CPU is slightly different, core i5 and i7). I fear of mixing them up, thought checking the exact logs is more appropriate.

Comment: Somebody actually reverse engineered the Fujitsu BIOS responsible for this, and it seems the dbx is loaded at startup into a small ram cache, but the new version is so much larger that the memory allocation fails and the system startup stops with an unrecoverable error. It's a really crazy way to load it, and it's also a really bad way to handle the failure -- and unfortunately it's not the first time this has happened with old Fujitsu firmware.

Comment: I think the i5/i7 shouldn't make much difference, and the data I need is the complete output of "sudo fwupdtool hwids" -- this report is also the reason we added https://gitlab.com/fwupd/lvfs-website/-/merge_requests/1417 -- it allows us to opt-out specific vendors and devices.